# On change of one cell, how to clear contents of another cell in excel table using vba. Also I need to expand the logic to entire column in that table

Tags: vba, excel-tables

Following VBA code works perfectly fine for clearing the contents of cell L4 when something in K4 is changed.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K4")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L4").ClearContents
End If
```

But now, let us say, I have a dynamically expanding excel table with the name "my_tbl", how can I change my above code to make it work for the dynamically expanding excel table "my_tbl".

[The attached image here contains a snapshot of my dynamic table which allows me to select States. But if I want to instead enter Countries, I want to clear my States data before being able to select more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIweI.png)

Comment: `ListObjects("my_tbl")` will refer to the table.

Comment: BigBen. Thank you for the pointer. I am extremely new to VBA. Would you please expand on how to use it?

Comment: I will point you to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the pointers. Here is what worked for me:

```
For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table1[loc1_type]")(i)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("Table1[loc1]")(i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
```